# Why "the" is used before the word "association" in the given sentence?

Tags: usage, definite-article

"The" association between socioeconomic conditions and health differed between countries of different economic development.

I know that "The" implies a particular association that is between "socioeconomic conditions" and "health".

But, What if I remove "the" before association? Like below:
Association between socioeconomic conditions and health differed between countries of different economic development.
There is still a sense of a 'particular association' that is between socioeconomic conditions and health. So, what is the need of using "the"?

Comment: I’d point out that in the sentence you cite, *association* and *differed beteeen* are working at cross purposes. I **think** what its author meant is that the association  **varied** across levels of economic development. Or *varied with* economic development.

Comment: Failure to attribute the author of an extract cited is plagiarism. Please provide the source of the piece or clarify that you are the original author. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In articles that summarize data, the definite article is often used with a specific datum or relationship the author has examined. Leaving the article out simply removes that nuance, but nothing much is lost as that notion is implicit in context.

> As we can see from the graph below, (the) correlation between GDP and defense spending varies by country.